# Logo Animation - Don't know where to begin

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-animation

I'm trying to have a cool little animation for my logo when it first appears on my Android App screen.

I have completely no idea how I would implement this idea though, OpenGL, Make a video and import it into an activity, other options?

Here is what I would like to accomplish:
[image]

Step 1: Start the bottom line of the triangle
Step 2: Start going up and back down and connect
Step 3: Have my custom logo fade into the triangle

Am I going out of my way trying to learn how to do this, or am I better off just having my logo show up as an image?

Comment: _It's [tag:opengl-es] since you're on android._

Comment: Thanks. That at least points me in a general direction. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easiest to just create a GIF for me in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are two options:

- You could do this programmatically. Use a time-based state machine to draw the triangle. If you're using an engine for android (andengine, libdgdx), there are abstractions to help you with the "infrastructure" code.
- You could make up an animated model in a 3D modeling program, and export an animated mesh or a sequence of images.

Best just show an image for now, and put your time into the app itself.

Comment: So, what's your take on the opengl-es.

Comment: Take any engine and go with it.